# How to get the position of a date cell when that date is selected,ios

Tags: ios, date, calendar, position

I had implemented a calendar control using the `NSCalenderController`. Now I am trying to get the position of a date cell when I select the particular date. How to get the position of a date cell when the date is selected by the user?

Comment: No am using the NSCalender control from the developer.apple.com

Comment: Ohh sorry,  I dont have idea abt that control..

Comment: yeah thats fine Dilip.Just now i analysed the code and i got the position of the selected date.

Comment: But can you tell me if i write a method in one class and how to call that method in another class

Comment: WOW.. you can post it as a answer to your own question so.. it will help some ppl  in future..

Comment: Is it a static method? i.e like something you write in Util class..

Comment: Can we post answers to our own questions dilip?

Comment: Yes you can,  I have did it for some questions.. it will help ppl in future..

Comment: Since it is a code I will post it as a answer..

Comment: Can you tell me if i declare the method in one class and how to use that method declaration in another class dilip?

Comment: If it is a not static class you have create a object for that class and using that object you can call the function if the function is public... if it is static then you can call using class name without creating object..

Comment: yes we can use the class name directly when the way is in static manner right

Comment: Yes you can use the class name directly if it is a static method..

Comment: yes am trying and i will let you know what error i got when i try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<7;j++)
{
int buttonNumber = i*7 + j;
DayButton *button = [dayButtons objectAtIndex:buttonNumber];
NSLog(@"the position of the date cells are========> %d",buttonNumber);
```

The buttonNumber will display the positions of the date cells of that calender.

Answer (score 1):

This is my Util class getHexColorCode is a method in Util class.  The - (Minus) indicates it is a static method..

```
    @interface Util : NSObject
    {

    }
+ (UIColor *) getHexColorCode: (NSString *) colorName;
```

I will call the function as

```
[Util getHexColorCode:@"Red"]
```

Hope this helps..